# CompletableFuture - Aggregating many results from a list for a Saga Fan-Out Pattern?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, completable-future, saga

I'm trying to model a fan-out saga pattern in a Java 11 spring component. The goal is to use the java concurrency classes to track the aggregate result status for many requests which are tracked in a list. The aim is then to take an action when they all succeed, one fails or does not respond.

My SagaObject, Request and RequestStatus classes are outline below, and show a List of request objects which have a status which will be updated from remote responses.

```
class SagaObject {
    private long sagaId;
    private List<Request> requests;
}

class Request {
    private long requestId;
    private RequestStatus status = RequestStatus.PENDING;
}

enum RequestStatus {
    PENDING,SUCCESS,FAILED;
}
```

In a number of examples I've seen, the approach is to create a CompletableFuture for each Request object. These instances
are then grouped using the 'allOf()' functionality.

```
// sudo code
// create a CompletableFuture per request
List<CompletableFuture<Request>> completableFutures =
    sagaObject.requests.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

// a CompletableFuture to track all the individual request
CompletableFuture<Request> allFutures = CompletableFuture
    .allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[sagaObject.requests.size()]));

allFutures.get();
// do some work based on the results of the 'allOf()'
if (allFutures.isDone ()) {
    // once all the CompletableFuture's have completed - we still need to iterate the list to check the outcome.
}
```

In my case - I've concerns about the number of requests in the list will be large. I sense creating a specific
CompletableFuture for each list request will create too large an overhead. Is this concern valid, what if the list has ~100,000 elements?

I have a sense I should have the 'SagaObject' implement one of the Callable/Supplier interfaces in a manner below

```
// sudo code
class SagaObject implements Callable<RequestStatus>, Supplier  {
    private long sagaId;
    private List<Request> requests;

    public RequestStatus call() throws Exception {
        // iterate the 'request' list and return SUCCESS/FAILED or an exception if PENDING remains
        return ..;
    }
}
```

which would then allow me to call the same code via ExecutorService in a manner like

```
// sudo code
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    try {   
        Future<RequestStatus> sagaFuture = executorService.submit(sagaObject);
        if (sagaFuture.isDone ()) {
            // 
            sagaFuture.get();
        }
```

I guess i'm not sure what is the best approach to breaking this problem down correctly so it aligns the concurrency
models provided by the JVM.
I'd be interested in any suggestions that stackoverflow and CompletableFuture users might suggest here.
Thanks

Comment: What happens if the JVM crashes in the middle of the processing the request?

Comment: In this scenarios, we rely on the idempotent nature of the operation and reprocess the data. We want to avoid the overhead of the DB backed saga implementations and use a in-memory concurrent solution.